# How to return an array which is an element of an multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, vba, join, multidimensional-array

To my knowledge an array in VBA (especialy if its a Variant type) can accept more or less anything as an element. A big advantage is that arrays can be elements of an array themselves, which makes the "higher" array containing the "lower" arrays multidimensional.

```
' Example
Dim TestArray() As Variant
Dim NestedArray1() As Variant
Dim NestedArray2() As Variant

NestedArray1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
NestedArray2 = Array(4, 5, 6)

TestArray = Array(NestedArray1, NestedArray2)
```

The structure is clear.
TestArray will have 2 Elements: NestedArray1, NestedArray2 which themselves are arrays with 3 elements containing (1,2,3) and (4,5,6). The Locals Window in the VBA editor also lists those element correctly.

But here comes the tricky part.

How do you access the "lower" arrays as a whole?

Usually accessing an arrays element is done like this

```
ArrayName(n)         ' One-dimensional
ArrayName(n,m,...)   ' Multidimensional

TestArray(1,2)       ' Using the above Example will return 2
```

So I'd expect

```
TestArray(1)
```

To return the equivalent of NestedArray1. TestArray(1) is even listed as an array with type Variant in the locals window just like any other array.

Unfortunatly this method is invalid.

Here's a concrete example:

Join(sourceArray, [ seperator ]) is a build-in function that expects an array and a seperator to return the arrays elements with the seperator in between the elements.

So:

```
Join(Array(1,2,3), ", ")
```

would return as a String:

```
1, 2, 3
```

But using the above example:

```
Join(TestArray(1), ", ")
```

Does unfortunately not work.

I know that Join() expects an one-dimensional source array, but is the inabilty to treat nested arrays as a valid input a limitation of the language itself?

Is there an elegant solution or does one always have to resolve to looping through every element of the nested array, creating a temporary new one and use that as an input for the function?

Comment: you have an array of arrays not a 2d array.  use `TestArray(1)(2)` which will return `2` the second item in the first array.

Comment: Using your code, `join(testarray(0),",")` gives `1,2,3` and `join(testarray(1),",")` gives `4,5,6`

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from a common newbie confusion with Variants in VBA.

A variant variable in VBA can hold an array.  This is not the same as an array of variants.

Consider the code below

```
Public Sub TestArrayWithVariants()

    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim myVariantArray(0 To 2) As Variant

    myArray = Split("Its,a,variant,containing, an,array", ",")
    ' The next line produces a Can't assign to array error
    myVariantArray = Split("Its,a,variant,containing, an,array", ",")

End Sub
```

Confusion arises because for one dimensional arrays there is no apparent difference in the syntax of an Variant containing an array and an Array of Variants.

e.g.

```
myArray(0)
myVariantArray(0)
```

However if we say

```
myArray(3)=Split("Its,a,variant,containing,an,array", ",")
```

Then to print 'variant' in position 2 of the second array would be

```
debug.Print myArray(3)(2)
```

This is different to if we declare myVariantArray as a multidimensional array

```
Dim myVariantArray(0 to 3,0 to 4)

myVariantArray(3,0)="Its"
myVariantArray(3,1)="an"
myVariantArray(3,2)"Array"
myVariantArray(3,3)"Containing"
myVariantArray(3,4)"Variants"
```

For a variant containing an array its best to think of the first dimension returning an anonymous array and when we index into that anonymous array we get whatever item is located at the index.

```
myArray(2)(4)
```

becomes

```
anonymous_array(4)
```

and so on.

If you are planning a data structure based on nested variants I'd strongly suggest that instead you use nested collections.